# Clarifications needed on Quartz 2.1 framework?

Tags: quartz-scheduler

Could you please clarify the following?

1. is current quartz 2.1 supports clustering for RAMJobStore?
2. in a clustered environment is there a way to specify via Quartz that a job run in all nodes?
3. in a clustered environment is there a way to specify via Quartz that a job run in a specific node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> a. is current quartz 2.1 supports clustering for RAMJobStore?

No, `RAMJobStore` works only within one JVM.

> b. in a clustered environment is there a way to specify via Quartz that a job run in all nodes?

No, it's not possible.

> c. in a clustered environment is there a way to specify via Quartz that a job run in a specific node?

No, cluster decides arbitrarily which node should run the job and you have no control over that. But see: [Select node in Quartz cluster to execute a job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847543).

Comment: The JDBCJobStore is slow in a clustered environment since it access the common tables, rows and RAMJobStore is faster than JBDCJobStore in a clustered environment since it keeps everything in memory.