# Liferay DXP Scheduled Tasks on cluster environment?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, cluster-computing, liferay-7, liferay-dxp

Need to run scheduler task on cluster environment.
 If cluster has 4 nodes say,
**node-1,**
node-2,
node-3,
node-4.

My scheduler always run on the  **node-1** only in all cases.
Is there any configuration for scheduler task run in particular node only.

I have followed this blog.

https://web.liferay.com/web/user.26526/blog/-/blogs/liferay-7-ce-liferay-dxp-scheduled-tasks

Comment: Why are you trying to move it to other nodes? Load balancing?

Answer (score 1):

You have only options to run it on a node or all nodes. You can't define what node should it be run on.

The scheduler is handled by Quartz.
[Select node in Quartz cluster to execute a job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847543/select-node-in-quartz-cluster-to-execute-a-job)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the scheduler only on a single node. You can create the Job manually on your bundle activation callback with `StorageType.MEMORY` and deploy that module only on that (desired)  host. However, this will make deployments more complicated.